# R Logistic regression on ffdf objects

Tags: r, regression, ff

I have built a logistic regression model using the **glm** function from the stats package.
I now would like to predict the outcome of this model on a large number of values, stored in a **"ffdf"** object (see ff package), however I do not find how to proceed:

1. **How can I create a subset of my ffdf object**, in order to keep only the variables (i.e. columns) to be used in my prediction? - needed to specify as an input in the predict function
2. How should I proceed next? Which function should be used between **predict(), predict.glm(), predict.bigglm()** (Maybe biglm package is helpful)?

Thank you in advance for your views on this!

Best regards

**UPDATE**

Thank you for your feedback BondedDust.
Let me be more precise, it is indeed a *coding question*, aiming at performing logistic regression based on an ffdf object (learning dataset), and predict the outcome of the model for another ffdf object (test dataset).

**(1/3) Learning data set**: ffdf object (created with ff package).

```
` class(train.random.sample)` >   
[1] "ffdf"
```

below is the structure of the ffdf object in case of needs:

```
`str(train.random.sample) ` >

List of 3   
 $ virtual: 'data.frame':   27 obs. of  7 variables:   
 .. $ VirtualVmode     : chr  "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" ...   
 .. $ AsIs             : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...   
 .. $ VirtualIsMatrix  : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...   
 .. $ PhysicalIsMatrix : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...   
 .. $ PhysicalElementNo: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...   
 .. $ PhysicalFirstCol : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...   
 .. $ PhysicalLastCol  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...   
 .. - attr(*, "Dim")= int  500000 27   
 .. - attr(*, "Dimorder")= int  1 2   
 $ physical: List of 27   
 .. $ id                : list()   
…   
 .. .. - attr(*, "class") =  chr [1:2] "ff_vector" "ff"   
 .. $ click             : list()   
…   
 .. .. - attr(*, "class") =  chr [1:2] "ff_vector" "ff"   
 .. $ hour              : list()   
…   
 .. .. - attr(*, "class") =  chr [1:2] "ff_vector" "ff"   
 .. $ C1                : list()   
…   
 .. .. - attr(*, "class") =  chr [1:2] "ff_vector" "ff"   
 .. $ banner_pos        : list()   
 ..  ..- attr(*, "physical")=Class 'ff_pointer' <externalptr>    
 ..  .. ..- attr(*, "vmode")= chr "integer"   
 ..  .. ..- attr(*, "maxlength")= int 500000   
 ..  .. ..- attr(*, "pattern")= chr "ffdf"   
 ..  .. ..- attr(*, "filename")= chr "anonymized.ff"   
 ..  .. ..- attr(*, "pagesize")= int 65536   
 ..  .. ..- attr(*, "finalizer")= chr "delete"   
 ..  .. ..- attr(*, "finonexit")= logi TRUE   
 ..  .. ..- attr(*, "readonly")= logi FALSE   
 ..  .. ..- attr(*, "caching")= chr "mmnoflush"   
 ..  ..- attr(*, "virtual")= list()   
 ..  .. ..- attr(*, "Length")= int 500000   
 ..  .. ..- attr(*, "Symmetric")= logi FALSE    
 .. .. - attr(*, "class") =  chr [1:2] "ff_vector" "ff"   
 .. $ site_id           : list()   
…   
 .. .. - attr(*, "class") =  chr [1:2] "ff_vector" "ff"   
 .. $ site_domain       : list()   
…   
 .. .. - attr(*, "class") =  chr [1:2] "ff_vector" "ff"   
 .. $ site_category     : list()   
…   
 .. .. - attr(*, "class") =  chr [1:2] "ff_vector" "ff"   
 .. $ app_id            : list()   
…   
 .. .. - attr(*, "class") =  chr [1:2] "ff_vector" "ff"   
 .. $ app_domain        : list()   
…  
 .. .. - attr(*, "class") =  chr [1:2] "ff_vector" "ff"   
 .. $ app_category      : list()   
…   
 .. .. - attr(*, "class") =  chr [1:2] "ff_vector" "ff"   
 .. $ device_id         : list()   
 …   
 .. .. - attr(*, "class") =  chr [1:2] "ff_vector" "ff"   
 .. $ device_ip         : list()   
….   
 .. .. - attr(*, "class") =  chr [1:2] "ff_vector" "ff"   
 .. $ device_os         : list()   
…   
 .. .. - attr(*, "class") =  chr [1:2] "ff_vector" "ff"   
 .. $ device_make       : list()   
…   
 .. .. - attr(*, "class") =  chr [1:2] "ff_vector" "ff"   
 .. $ device_model      : list()   
…   
 .. .. - attr(*, "class") =  chr [1:2] "ff_vector" "ff"   
 .. $ device_type       : list()   
…   
 .. .. - attr(*, "class") =  chr [1:2] "ff_vector" "ff"   
 .. $ device_conn_type  : list()   
…   
 .. .. - attr(*, "class") =  chr [1:2] "ff_vector" "ff"   
 .. $ device_geo_country: list()   
…   
 .. .. - attr(*, "class") =  chr [1:2] "ff_vector" "ff"   
 .. $ C17               : list()   
…   
 .. .. - attr(*, "class") =  chr [1:2] "ff_vector" "ff"   
$ row.names:  NULL   
- attributes: List of 2   
 .. $ names: chr [1:3] "virtual" "physical" "row.names"   
 .. $ class: chr "ffdf"
```

**(2/3) Logistic regression** based on learning dataset:

*Objective is to learn/ predict ‘click’ outcome based on ‘baser_pos’ input*

```
`logreg1 <- glm(click ~ banner_pos, data = train.random.sample, family = "binomial")   
summary(logreg1)` >   


Call:
glm(formula = click ~ banner_pos, family = "binomial", data = train.random.sample)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.0555  -0.6495  -0.5951  -0.5951   1.9071  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -1.641416   0.004702 -349.12   <2e-16 xxx
banner_pos   0.192534   0.007595   25.35   <2e-16 xxx
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘xxx’ 0.001 ‘xx’ 0.01 ‘x’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 458848  on 499999  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 458215  on 499998  degrees of freedom
AIC: 458219

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

`class(logreg1)`>
[1] "glm" "lm"
```

**(3/3)Test dataset**: ffdf object (created with ff package).

```
`class(df.test)` >   
[1] "ffdf"
```

*Test dataset structure is identical to training dataset, with ~4.8m rows*

```
`str(df.test)`>   

List of 3   
 $ virtual: 'data.frame':   26 obs. of  7 variables:   
 .. $ VirtualVmode     : chr  "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" ...   
.. $ AsIs             : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...   
.. $ VirtualIsMatrix  : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...   
.. $ PhysicalIsMatrix : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...   
.. $ PhysicalElementNo: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...   
.. $ PhysicalFirstCol : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...   
.. $ PhysicalLastCol  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...   
.. - attr(*, "Dim")= int  4769401 26   
.. - attr(*, "Dimorder")= int  1 2   
$ physical: List of 26   
…
```

I could not succeed in predicting click outcome.
I first tried to create a dataframe or ffdf object containing the banner_pos variable:

```
`modeldata <- df.test[["banner_pos"]]`
```

Then I tried to predict the outcome:

```
`predict.glm(object = logreg1, newdata = modeldata, type = "response")`

Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : 
  cannot coerce class "c("ff_vector", "ff")" to a data.frame
```

Is there something wrong in my code? Should I use other function leveraging other packages such as biglm?
Many thanks in advance for your views on that issue,
Best regards

Comment: You should not ask us to guess at the methods you used. Provide code and output of `str(ff_object)`. You would not expect to use "predict" functions until you had created model objects. That second request is suggesting to me that you have not really done this sort of R operation in the past on regular dataframe data. Voting to close as too broad. If you edit to make this more of a coding questions, perhaps others will disagree with me and you can get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something similar as this will score your `ffdf` alongside your `glm`.

```
require(ff)
df.test$score <- ff(as.numeric(NA), length = nrow(df.test))
chunks <- chunk(df.test)
for(chunkrangeindex in chunks){
  df.test$score[chunkrangeindex] <- predict(object = logreg1, newdata = df.test[chunkrangeindex, ], type = "response")
}
```

Comment: Thank you jwijffels. I have however a new error with your suggestion while running the for() loop: opening ff C:/Users/XXXXX/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpCE64Sq/ffdf218891f61b7.ff
Error: file.access(filename, 0) == 0 is not TRUE. I can't understand this error.. Do you have any idea? Many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: The error states that the ff file is no longer there on the disk where it was before. You probably closed R and forgot to save your df.test ffdf with either ffsave or ffdfsave.

Comment: Thank you jwijffels. I had indeed an issue while saving my ffdf objects. Using save.ffdf instead of ffsave helped! (your document [here](http://www.bnosac.be/images/blog/user2013_presentation_ffbase.pdf) is very interesting by the way).   
I now have a new error once launching the ‘for’ loop, which is: 
**Error in `[[<-.ff`(`*tmp*`, chunkrangeindex, value = c(0.162272524618093,  :  i must have length 1**  
Would you have an idea?  
Many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: yes, I mistyped something. It should be df.test$score[chunkrangeindex] instead of df.test$score[[chunkrangeindex]]. Updated the answer accordingly.